# Booting into custom recovery with a locked bootloader

Tags: rooting, bootloader, twrp

I'm planning to flash a custom ROM on my device, but too lazy to take backups.. My favorite backup tool being Titanium Backup, I want root access on my device before I unlock the bootloader. But unforunately to flash the SuperSU file I need to have a custom recovery on my device as my stock recovery doesn't allow me to flash SuperSU zip. And to flash a custom recovery I need to unlock my bootloader. Can I however boot into Team Win recovery without unlocking my bootloader through this command?

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```

This will allow me to root my device and take backups easily before I unlock my device bootloader. So is it safe for me to do so?

Comment: Just a side note, if you manage to root your phone without unlocking it, then you probably won't need to unlock it to install a custom recovery/ROM either.

Comment: You're right. I could use Flashify to flash TWRP but I won't do it as flashing through fastboot has its own essence and fun.

Comment: You can't `fastboot boot` with a custom image and a locked bootloader, at least for my Nexus 6P, 7.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

No, you can't use `fastboot boot` to boot into a custom recovery if the bootloader is locked (as Jerry Chin noted in a [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130463/booting-into-custom-recovery-with-a-locked-bootloader#comment221337_130463)).

## Longer Answer

[Android Security Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593275811) says in *Chapter 13: System Updates and Root Access* (in section *Recovery*, subsection *Custom Recoveries*):

> A custom recovery is a recovery OS build created by a third party (not
>   the device manufacturer). Because it is created by a third party, a
>   custom recovery is not signed with the manufacturer’s keys, and
>   therefore a device’s bootloader needs to be unlocked in order to boot
>   or flash it.

And in *Chapter 10: Device Security* (in section *Controlling OS Boot-Up and Installation*, subsection *Bootloader*):

> In order to ensure device integrity, consumer devices are shipped with
>   locked bootloaders, which either disallow flashing and booting system
>   images completely or allow it only for images that have been signed by the
>   device manufacturer.

Thus, if you try to use `fastboot boot twrp.img`, the bootloader will find out that `twrp.img` is not signed by the manufacturer's key, and would refuse to boot into it.

And just in case we are not sure whether `fastboot` allows bypassing the restrictions that a locked bootloader introduce, we also have in *Chapter 13: System Updates and Root Access* (in section *Bootloader*, subsection *Fastboot Mode*):

> Commands that modify device partitions, such as the various flash variations, and commands that boot custom kernels, such as the boot command,
>   are not allowed when the bootloader is locked.